# changing the parameter list of a virtual function in a derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

**code 1**

```
#include<iostream>
struct b
{
    virtual void f1(void)
    {
        std::cout<<"b->f1\n";   
    }
};

struct d:public b
{
    void f1(int x)
    {
        std::cout<<"d->f1\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    b *p;
    d d1;
    p=(b*)&d1;
    
    p->f1(4); // this gives error
    
}
```

**Output**

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'b::f1(int)'
```

**code 2**

```
#include<iostream>
struct b
{
    virtual void f1(void)
    {
        std::cout<<"b->f1\n";   
    }
};

struct d:public b
{
    virtual void f1(int x)
    {
        std::cout<<"d->f1\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    b *p;
    d d1;
    p=(b*)&d1;
    
    p->f1(4); // this gives error
    
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Error] no matching function for call to b::f1(int)
```

In 2nd code, just I write explicitly `virtual` in derived class fun.

for both cases, compiler is doing early binding as it is finding these function in base class. Means the derived class function `f1` is not becoming virtual ?

Why it is not becoming virtual function in case 1 ? and also in case 2 where I wrote explicitly `virtual` keyword ?

Also I read that virtual functions should use in just case of **over-riding** not in case of **over-hiding**, is that true ?

Comment: What would `p->f1(4)` do if the actual type of `*p` were `b` or some other class inheriting `b` but not `d`?

Comment: `b::f1()` and `d::f1(int)` are mostly unrelated functions, they just share the same name and form an overload set, no `override` here.

Comment: Consider this: The whole point of polymorphism/virtual functions is that code can use a pointer to `b`to call methods  of `d` *without even knowing `d` exists*.

Comment: What do you mean by "over-hiding"? Hiding (or shadowing) methods from base class by methods in derived class?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `p=(b*)&d1;` should be written as `p=&d1;`. There is an implicit conversions from pointer-to-derived to ponter-to-base. Don't write casts unless you really, really need them. And even then, don't write casts.

Comment: Add `virtual void f1(int) = 0;` in `b` if you want to be able to call that overload via a base class pointer. Note that it also makes `b` abstract, so you can't instantiate `b`. Also, add `override` to functions which you _think_ override a `virtual` function. Your `d::f1(int)` does not override.

Comment: @Jarod42 got it. Thanks

Comment: @Yksisarvinen consider `void f1(void)` and `void f2(void)` present in base class and `void f1(int)` present in derived class. consider `d1` as derived class object. Then `d1.f2()` search first in derived class and it not find `f2` function then it search it in base class there it found it and execute. done. Now `d1.f1()` search first in derived class it found it so it not goes in base class to find it. but in derived class `f1` is present with arg. so gives error. This is over-hiding of base class function `void f1(void)` via function in derived class. `void f1(int)`

Comment: The `override` keyword was added in C++11 to address this very issue.  If `d::f1()` were marked as `override` (`void f1(int x) override`), then the compiler would refuse to compile this code anymore, since there is no matching `f1()` method in `b` to override.  An override MUST have the exact same parameter list, and the exact same (or at least covariant) return type. `d::f1()` does not satisfy that requirement, thus it is *overloading* `f1()` rather than *overriding* it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My teacher says it is over-hiding is he right ? or it is just over-loading. I explained to user `@Yksisarvinen` in comment above you. am I right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane you need to learn proper terminology. There is no term "over-hiding" in C++, it is just "hiding", or "shadowing". And "over-loading" is "overloading". But yes, in this case, `d::f1` is *hiding* `b::f1` and not *overriding* it. See [Hiding of all overloaded methods with same name in base class](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-89/amp/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main point behind virtual functions is that code can use a pointer to a base class to call methods of a child class *without even knowing the child class exists*.

In other words your code is effectively equivalent to this:

```
#include<iostream>

struct b
{
    virtual void f1(void)
    {
        std::cout<<"b->f1\n";   
    }
};

// Implemented somewhere else entirely.
b* some_function_that_might_returns_a_d();

int main()
{
    b *p;
    p = some_function_that_might_returns_a_d();
    
    p->f1(4); // this gives error    
}
```

All the compiler sees is `f1(void)`, it has nothing else to work with. That's why it complains that `f1(4)` makes no sense.

The fact that the compiler happens to be able to see `d` in your example is just incidental, and doesn't affect anything. As long as you are calling methods on a pointer of type `b`, you'll be able to invoke methods on *any* subclass of `b`, even on classes that don't exist yet. However, for this to work, only methods that have been declared by the base class can be used.

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting your answer clearly. By the way `jarod42` comment clears my doubt. `The main point behind virtual functions is that code can use a pointer to a base class to call methods of a child class without even knowing the child class exists.` in this statement by you I am not getting `without even knowing the child class exists.` can you elaborate please.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Look at the code I posted in my answer,  `some_function_that_might_returns_a_d()` could be implemented in a different .cpp file, maybe even a separate library, yet everything up to `p->f1(4)` is fine. if `d` had a `f1(void)` method, you could call it from this main, despite this cpp file never being told that `d` exists.

Comment: I am not getting. `some_function_that_might_returns_a_d()` returns object of class `d` then how come it doesn't know that `d` exists.

Comment: The signature of the function returns a `b*`, but nothing stops the implementation from returning a `d` object in that `b*` pointer.